# Invoking a controller method on submission of a form ? CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI , I am trying to call a controller method on form submission.I am not able to get to that particular method i.e hello

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php base_url();?>Welcome/hello">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="user_name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
```

**Welcome is the controller class as**

```
<?php

  class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');

    }
    function hello(){
      echo "Here in Hello";
    }
 }
```

**Base URL in config.php is as**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/rdc/index.php/';
```

When I click on login button it says

**The requested URL /rdc/Welcome/hello was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 1):

Lowercase 'W': `action="<?php base_url();?>welcome/hello"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
view page:

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/hello">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="user_name"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/rdc/index.php/';
```

controller page:`<?php class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    public function hello(){
      echo "Here in Hello";
    }
 }`

Comment: I tried but this didn't work . Actually welcome is my defualt controller is there any issue with this ?

Comment: there has some change i did.you aren't echo base_url() on views page.use http on config.php page.use public function on controller page.

Answer (score 0):

first of remove index.php from your $config file like this.

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/rdc/index.php/';
```

change it to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/rdc/';
```

after that put in form url

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/hello">
```

hopefully this will resolve your problem

Regards